# Salesforce-to-Wordpress: WP Options Table not populating with json from SF

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, salesforce, integration

I am attempting to populate a WordPress site with data from Salesforce. Sort of similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27208188/php-sending-data-to-salesforce-with-curl-but-not-posting-in-database?newreg=8f4cc6a003f74743bd41ff8cbd98daba) maybe except I'm going in the opposite direction. I am basing my code quite a bit on [this example](http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/interact-with-the-forcecom-rest-api-from-php), which worked fine for me when I tried it on it's own but not so much once I tried it with Wordpress.

From the example, I only replaced demo_rest.php with the code below,changed that final line in oauth_callback.php to return to my options page in WordPress, made the proper changed to config.php, and replaced index.html. When I did that I see in Salesforce that I am indeed logging in from my plugin, but nothing is coming back to WordPress from there. It's not displaying in the window I want or updating the the mysql database with the json that should result. What am I doing wrong?

My code.

```
<?php

/*Assign global variables*/
$plugin_url = WP_PLUGIN_URL . '/my-plugin';
$options = array();


// adds plugin settings page in wordpress admin menu
function salesforce_menu(){

add_options_page( // wordpres helper function to add a settings page
    'Salesforce to WordPress Integrator',
    'Salesforce Integration',
    'manage_options',
    'salesforce-integrator',
    'salesforce_options_page'
    );
}

add_action('admin_menu','salesforce_menu');


function salesforce_options_page(){

    if ( !current_user_can('manage_options')){
        wp_die ('You do not have sifficient permissions to access this page.');

    }


global $plugin_url;
global $options;    


if( $access_token != '') { 


    $response = get_stories($instance_url, $access_token);//This is where I'm probably getting messed up. I'm trying to call the get_stories function (defined later)

    $options['response'] = $response;
    $options['last_updated'] =time();

    update_option ('storybank_approved', $options); //wp helper function to update the options table, hopefully with the results of my call to the API. 



}



$options = get_option('storybank_approved');

if ($options !=''){
    $response = $options['response'];
}

var_dump  ($response); //I want this to show me the json on my settings page just to ensure that I have a response, but it looks like I don't

    require('includes/options-page-wrapper.php');
}

//get salesforce records

function get_stories($instance_url, $access_token) {
    $query = "SELECT Id, Name from salesforce_Object__c LIMIT 100";
  $url = "$instance_url/services/data/v20.0/query?q=" . urlencode($query) ;

   $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
            array("Authorization: OAuth $access_token"));

    $json_response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl); 

    $response =json_decode($json_response,true); 
    $total_size = $response['totalSize'];

    echo "$total_size record(s) returned<br/><br/>"; 

    foreach ((array) $response['records'] as $record) {                                   
        echo $record['Id'] . ", " . $record['Name']. "<br/>"; 

    }
    echo "<br/>";
    }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The getStories function is not returning a value.
$response = get_stories($instance_url, $access_token); // has to return something.

//for example, I deleted the rest of the code for simplicity.

```
function get_stories($instance_url, $access_token) {
       $response =json_decode($json_response,true); 
        return $response; 
}
```